# Timing using cudaEvent****() VS clock_gettime()

Tags: cuda, timing

I'm trying to time my code. I have been told that cudaEvent****() can be applied. at the meantime, my original code use clock_gettime() to time. I print results measured by both cudaEvent****() and clock_gettime() as follows. That is what I'm really confused about.

measured by cudaEvent****()

- init data structure: 1971.517578ms
- establish context: 0.007296ms
- rearrange data: 234.271423ms
- copy data: 53.402176ms
- time stepping: 17221.333984ms

measured by clock_gettime()

- init data structure: 1.802874s
- establish context: 20.541891s
- rearrange data: 0.235464s
- copy data: 0.051851s
- time stepping: 8.429955s

note:

- init data structure: totally work on CPU
- establish context: one line only: cudaFree((void*)0);
- rearrange data: totally work on CPU
- copy data: transfer data from host to device
- time stepping: two kernel functions are involved

Q1: The time spent of "establish context" measured by cudaEvent****() (0.0072ms) is quite different from that measured by clock_gettime() (~20.5s). Actually, this part has only one line which establishes a context.
cudaFree(0)
How does this vast difference happen ?

Q2: The time spent of "time stepping" measured by cudaEvent****() (~17.221s) is twice as much as that measured by clock_gettime() (~8.43s). Someone tells me that asynchronization can be a possible reason, but I don't really get it. can anyone help me get through it ?

Q3: The wall clock time spent is really close to the time measured by clock_gettime(). However, I'm told that cudaEvent****() is preferable in timing a cuda code. I don't know which one I should shoose.

===============================update===================================
The following is a part of my code in which some timing functions and macros are defined.

```
#define TIMING 1
#if TIMING
double get_time()
{
    struct timespec time;
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &time);
    return (double)time.tv_sec + (double)time.tv_nsec * 1.0e-9 ;
}
#endif
#define CUDATIMING 0
#if CUDATIMING
#define cuda_timing_init \
    cudaEvent_t startEvent, stopEvent;\
    float timeEvent;\
    cudaEventCreate(&startEvent);\
    cudaEventCreate(&stopEvent);
#define cuda_timing_begin \
    cudaEventRecord(startEvent, 0);
#define cuda_timing_stop(str) \
    cudaEventRecord(stopEvent, 0);\
    cudaEventSynchronize(stopEvent);\
    cudaEventElapsedTime(&timeEvent, startEvent, stopEvent);\
    printf("time spent of %s: %fms\n", str, timeEvent);
#define cuda_timing_destroy \
    cudaEventDestroy(startEvent);\
    cudaEventDestroy(stopEvent);
#endif
```

I use these functions and macros to time.

===========================update 20150823===============================

Here is the basic structure of my code including timing. I'm not sure if it can help to solve my timing issue.

```
void
copy_float_from_host_to_dev(float *h_p, float **d_pp, int size)
{
    if_error(cudaMalloc(d_pp, size));
    if_error(cudaMemcpy(*d_pp, h_p, size, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));
}

void
copy_int_from_host_to_dev(int *h_p, int **d_pp, int size)
{
    if_error(cudaMalloc(d_pp, size));
    if_error(cudaMemcpy(*d_pp, h_p, size, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));
}

int
main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    // init 
    // totally CPU codes        
    // ......
#if TIMING
    double t1, t2, t3, t4, t5, t6; 
    t1 = get_time();
#endif
#if CUDATIMING
    cuda_timing_init;
    cuda_timing_begin;
#endif
    // init data structure
    // totally CPU codes
    // ......
#if TIMING
    t2 = get_time();
#endif
#if CUDATIMING
    cuda_timing_stop("init data structure");
    cuda_timing_begin;
#endif
    // establish context
    cudaFree((void*)0);
#if TIMING
    t3 = get_time();
#endif
#if CUDATIMING
    cuda_timing_stop("establish context");
    cuda_timing_begin;
#endif
    // rearrange data
    // totally CPU codes
    // data on CPU side has different structure
    // compared to data on GPU side, so I need
    // to rearrange it.
    // ......
#if TIMING
    t4 = get_time();
#endif
#if CUDATIMING
    cuda_timing_stop("rearrange data");
    cuda_timing_begin;
#endif
    // copy data from host to device
    // about 10 copies. the following are 2 of them
       // all use copy_float/int_from_host_to_dev 
    // h_lap --> d_lap
    copy_float_from_host_to_dev(h_lap, &d_lap, lapsize); 
    // h_etol --> d_etol
    copy_int_from_host_to_dev(h_etol, &d_etol, etolsize); 
    // ......
#if TIMING
    t5 = get_time();
#endif
#if CUDATIMING
    cuda_timing_stop("copy data");
    cuda_timing_begin;
#endif
    // time stepping
    for(step = 1; step < para->nstep; step++)
    {
    /* kernel_1: matrix-vector multiplication.
     * The matrix is special, so multiplication 
     * can be very fast.  
     * atomic operations are involved
     * no data transfers between host and device */
    kernel_1<<<32768, 128>>>(......);
    /* kernel_2: vector operations.
     * Assuming that a,b,c,d are vectors,
     * what kernel_2 does is: a=2*a-b+c*d 
     * no data transfers between host and device */
    kernel_2<<<16384, 128>>>(......);
    }
#if TIMING
    t6 = get_time();
    printf("total time: %fs\n", t6-t1);
    printf("  init data structure: %fs\n", t2-t1);
    printf("  establish context: %fs\n", t3-t2);
    printf("  rearrange data: %fs\n", t4-t3);
    printf("  copy data: %fs\n", t5-t4);
    printf("  time stepping: %fs\n", t6-t5);
#endif
#if CUDATIMING
    cuda_timing_stop("time stepping");
    cuda_timing_destroy;
#endif

    // destroy data structure
    // totally CPU codes
    // ......

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Without seeing the code, it will be just about impossible to say.

Comment: The code is a bit long, but I think I can update my question to show you how I time the "establish context" part. @talonmies

Answer (score 2):

You have only provided a single code example, so I can only provide a single answer:

> The time spent of "establish context" measured by cudaEvent****() (0.0072ms) is quite different from that measured by clock_gettime() (~20.5s). Actually, this part has only one line which establishes a context. cudaFree(0) How does this vast difference happen ?

Your assumption that the `cudaFree` call estabilshes the CUDA context is incorrect. Lazy context establishment happens with the first call that needs to interact directly with the context. In this case it is your event timing code that is establishing the context, so the `cudaFree` call is basically free. That is why there is a large wallclock time difference between the two timing methods.

Comment: Thanks very much ! You really get my first problem solved ! I have updated my question by adding the basic structure of my code. I'm not sure if it helps. By the way, why context establishment costs so much time? @talonmies

Comment: @Lin: I'm sorry but I am not going to keep re-answering this question every time you get the urge to update it with more incomplete and confusing details.